# Sound plays back in Android Emulator but not on my G1

Tags: java, android, resources, audio, wav

For my Android game prototype, I'm playing back .wav resources using:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, soundID);
mp.start();
```

This works fine in the Eclipse Android emulator, but when I run the same program on my G1, no sound happens. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: media volume turned down? different devices have different volume controls, check volume in your usual mp3 player?

Comment: The volume is turned on, just checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it this way:

```
Uri myUri = ....; // initialize Uri here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

instead of MediaPlayer.create()

Comment: I was under the impression that create() called prepare()? But will try.